# Azure DevOps "Prepare analysis on SonarQube" task fails against our Azure hosted SonarQube server with a Let's Encrypt wildcard cert

Tags: java, ssl, sonarqube, azure-devops, lets-encrypt

When running the SonarQube task on the Windows Hosted Agent I get this error right away.

### [error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"}

The error is apparently related to what's discussed in this [Let's Encrypt signing explanation](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).

Using the info on that page as a guide and in an attempt to fix the problem I've created a predecessor task in the DevOps job to add to the Java keystore on the DevOps Agent box all the certs in the chain up from our wildcard to the issuer (including cross-signers). I'm able to do that but I still get the error from the follow-on Sonar task.

When I invoke curl against the /api/server/version endpoint from the Agent I get the error "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate".

It's my understanding that the Sonar task would rely on the Java keystore but that curl doesn't. That makes it seem like for both apps to work, I need to add these trusted certs in 2 places but I haven't found even one them. Can anyone guide me to instructions for resolving this issue?

Dave

UPDATE: Realizing that the "problem" cert might be helpful. You can get it here [link](https://sonarqube.kalderos.com)

Comment: You need to register all keys to the keystore. Have a look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/ssl-in-java)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I was doing that but it wasn't fixing the problem. I'm happy to report though that I did find the solution and, in case anyone does the same dumb thing like me, here's the summary. The real problem was that the server.crt I was using for my apache based site only had the wildcard cert in it. It needed to have the chain to the Let's Encrypt issuer in it as well. Once added, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that the root of this issue was that I needed to import SonarQuBe certificate as a trust ceritificate in the JRE certificate store.

You can try the following steps:

1. Download keystore explorer from [here](https://keystore-explorer.org)
2. Open $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
3. enter PW: changeit (Can be changeme on Mac)
4. Import your .crt file.
5. Save and replace cacerts file.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when your SonarQube instance URLs SSL configuration has incomplete Chain issues. (You can get more details or analyse the SSL configuration [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest))

In my case, I was using an Nginx reverse proxy configured with SSL and **ssl_certificate** on the **server block** was referenced to the .pem certificate file instead of the chained certificate.

This is how you can create the chained certificate from the files you download from the CA:

1. Renaming cert and intermediate cert files
   a) random_name.crt => yourdomain.com.crt
   b) gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt => intermediate.crt
2. create the chained certificate
   cat yourdomain.com.crt intermediate.crt >> yourdomain.com.chained.crt
3. Use that in your web-servers server block (Ex: Nginx)

   server {

   ```
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;

        server_name         yourdomain.com;
        ssl_certificate     /PATH_TO_FILE/yourdomain.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /PATH_TO_FILE/yourdomain-private.key;

        location / {
                ..........;
        }
   ```

   }