# how to create a sonarqube task with truststore into azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I wanna create a sonarqube task into azure devops
the task looks just like this:

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQube'
    projectKey: 'abc'
    projectName: 'abc'
    scannerMode: 'Other'

- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.291ed61f-1ee4-45d3-b1b0-bf822d9095ef.SonarQubePublish@4
  displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
```

but I got the error:

```
[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"}
```

Actually I must add truststore into the task just like this:

```
- task: Maven@3
    name: MavenSonar
    inputs:
      goals: org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar
      options: -s mvn/settings.xml -B
      mavenOptions: -Dmaven.test.skip=$(test.disabled) -Dsonar.login=$(sonar.token) -Dsonar.host.url=$(sonar.url) -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mvn/sonar.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

our sonarqube server url is with https, so in order to login sonarqube, the credential will be needed. but I don't know, how to add it into pipeline task.

but my project is a only frontend projekct with angular, how can I use truststore in my pipeline.

can somebody help me??

Comment: Which type of certificate do you use? Please try using a `LetsEncrypt` certificate. Reference this ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303439/azure-devops-prepare-analysis-on-sonarqube-task-fails-against-our-azure-hosted

Comment: I have created service connection for sonarqube. but my server url ist https, that means that I must uses some certificate to login sonarqube website.

Comment: Hi Andy, can you give me more information? what is next step for me?